# Getting message in angularjs chat application without refresh.

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am using angularjs 1.5.5 and codeigniter 3.0 .

When i send message from one user to another user offline it working fine but after uploaded the project I come to know that it is not working properly because receiver received message in that time when it send some message to the sender.

```
$scope.sendSenderMessage = function(bsid,srid,message)

 {
    //bsid is sender id while srid is receiver id
    $http.post(url + 'c_chat/sendSenderMessageJson', {
      'bsid'    : bsid ,
      'srid'    : srid ,
      'message' : message

    })
    .success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.startChat(fksc_id);

    });
  }

After sending message through the following function i get the data: 

$scope.startChat = function(fksc_id=false)
 {

    if(fksc_id)
     {

      $http.get(url + 'c_chat/startChatJson/' + 
      fksc_id).success(function(data)
      {
        //console.log(data);
        $scope.chats = data;

      });
     }
 }
```

And in my view:

```
 <div ng-init="startChat()">
    <div  ng-repeat="chat in chats" > 

       <div class="col-md-6">

       <p >{{chat.sender_message}}</p> 
       </div>

       </div>
```

chat.sender_message is the real message for both sender and receiver. The problem is that receiver message is show only when message is sent or page is refreshed.

My data base table is like

```
message_id     fksc_id      fkrc_id     sender_message
```

Comment: search for websockets. or give service call after every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you could use angular timeout to refresh scope every n seconds:-

```
 var timer = $timeout( function refresh(){
   //your code to refresh scope
    timer = $timeout(refresh, 100000);
}, 100000);
```

Or you could use sockets **Socket.io** to emit the event and refresh the scope:

something like this:

```
socket.on('receive:message', function (message) {
   //your code to refresh scope
  });
```

I'll recommend
[Socket IO NPM LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-socket-io)